# Consider Noise in Link Budgets

Tags: amplifier, rf, communication, wireless, signal-to-noise

I want to verify the range of my RF-system for a university project.
I use two transceivers ([Datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cc1200.pdf?ts=1629199809644&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FCC1200%253Futm_source%253Dgoogle%2526utm_medium%253Dcpc%2526utm_campaign%253Depd-con-null-prodfolderdynamic-cpc-pf-google-wwe%2526utm_content%253Dprodfolddynamic%2526ds_k%253DDYNAMIC%2BSEARCH%2BADS%2526DCM%253Dyes%2526gclid%253DCj0KCQjwvO2IBhCzARIsALw3ASpsOIp2_FnLDYxv0t4BE3T2OMTgO5wqulrg0OLOCr2hOEc7EtyWoWcaAjIyEALw_wcB%2526gclsrc%253Daw.ds)) and one power amplifier on the transmit side ([Datasheet](https://rfbayinc.com/products_pdf/product_3_515.pdf)). The target range is 120 km over which I have a clear line of sight (Tx side is a rocket; Rx antenna is looking to the sky).

What I did, was to sum up all power contributions, assume some losses and to pick the right sensitivity from my transceivers datasheet (-111 dBm @ 433 mHz and 38 kbps):

[image] 

I concluded from the positive margin that the link would be possible. 
However, my professor criticized this and told me I couldn't be sure since I didn't consider noise. 

**How can I consider the influence of noise on my system?** Isn't some "standard" noise already included into the sensitivity parameter of the receiver? My Tx power amplifier has a noise figure of 6.5 dB, do I have to consider this with something like Friis equation? But then, what would be the noise figure of my transmitter?

Comment: When I consider noise I 1) consider that noise is also (and behaves like) a signal. 2) what matters in receivers is SNR, the S/N ratio. So the TX PA having a NF = 6.5 dB means that that TX PA degrades the SNR by 6.5 dB. So I would advise to add the SNR to your table and see what SNR you end up with at the receiver. Is the SNR high enough? Have you read any articles like: https://www.eetimes.com/understanding-noise-figures-in-radio-receivers/ ?

Comment: Okay, so I have my Output Power (30 dBm), an assumed Transmitter Noise Power (-128 dBm with T=290°K and B=104kHz) and a power amplifier Noise Figure (6.5 dB). Is my SNR at Tx then: SNR = 30 + 128 - 6.5 = 151.5 dB ? Then I subtract all losses, add antenna noise and get the SNR at Rx Input?

Comment: *Is my SNR at Tx then: SNR = 30 + 128 - 6.5 = 151.5 dB* I think that is indeed correct. The losses affect noise and signal equally so the SNR isn't affected, you would get that same 151.5 dB SNR at the input of the RX.